# How define the my OpenUI5 application by a graphic editor

Tags: sapui5

I'm a OpenUI5 developer. I create easily new applications, but I I have to use a code approach (XMLview - in my case - js or json).
Could you suggest an alternative mode to create a interface? (like android or iOS editor - drag&drop - to realize my pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what significance you are placing on the "Open" part of "OpenUI5", but you may or may not be aware of SAP's [Rapid Developer Environment aka RDE](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/SAP_RDE/frameset.htm). There are visual design tools for the view parts of UI5 apps. You could possibly use that and then export the results.

Comment: check out this tool in SCN, http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/12/18/fast-sapui5-develop-tool